# How to Inject DBApi into a trait component in play framework 2.5?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I upgraded to play framework 2.5, and a lot of changes needed to take a place, the hardest one is how to use dependency injection with a trait, since I can not transform my trait into a class or object because I'am  using this trait in other places: extends and imports usage. 
this is my trait:

```
trait PlayDataSourceSlice extends DataSourceSlice {

  import play.api.Play.current
  def dataSource = DB.getDataSource()
}
```

the play indicates :

```
 @deprecated("Inject DBApi into your component", "2.5.0")
```

I tried the following but I got `NullPointerException`

```
trait PlayDataSourceSlice extends DataSourceSlice {

  @Inject private var dbApi: DBApi = _
  lazy val getDataSrc: Database = dbApi.database("default")
  def dataSource = getDataSrc.dataSource
}
```

Comment: Inject it into the class(es) that extends your trait

Comment: what about objects that extends this trait and imports?

Comment: Turn your objects into classes and make them `@singleton`.  I don't know what you mean by imports